# Pre-Populating form data using liftweb

Tags: forms, scala, lift

How do I pre-populate a form input field while rendering it.

What I want to achieve is display a form with a input field pre-populated. This value is to be populated dynamically.

This is my form

```
<form class="lift:Expense.add?form=post">
  Date: <input type="text" id="date" name="date" /><br />
  Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" /><br /> 
  Towards: <input type="text" name="towards" /><br /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

This is the corresponding snippet

```
def add = {
  var dateParam = ""
  var amount: Int = 0
  var towards: String = ""

  def process() {
    S.redirectTo("/")
  }

  "name=date" #> SHtml.onSubmit(dateParam = _) &
  "name=amount" #> SHtml.onSubmit(value => asInt(value).foreach(amount = _)) &
  "name=towards" #> SHtml.onSubmit(towards = _) &
  "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(process)
}
```

What I want is to set the server date to the date input field and save it when I submit the form. For now my problem is how do I display the date.

Comment: Got a solution, would like to know if this is the only way to accomplish it.This is what I have done, added this line `"name=date [value]" #> "Date"` This will set the value of the input field with Date, This can be changed to whatever desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do that. The first is to set each attribute independently, like this:

```
"name=amount" #> SHtml.onSubmit(value => asInt(value).foreach(amount = _)) &
"name=amount [value]" #> amount
```

The other would be to use a Lift component to replace the whole input. Something like:

```
"name=amount" #> SHtml.text(amount, value => asInt(value).foreach(amount = _))
```

The difference between the two approaches is that in the first, you are only adding specific attributes to the element in your template. In the second, you are replacing the entire element with an `input type="text"` created by Lift.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. So the second way will bind the onSubmit functionality as well?

Comment: Got it answered by trying it out. Thank you very much.